# show details of all orders placed by customer

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, jsp, spring-mvc

I am developing an E-Commerce website(Spring MVC, java, mySql, Hibernate) for my college project. I have various models like customer,product,orders,custOrderHistory, etc.

I am able to show all customer details(in admin page) and all products for a customer to browse through.

But the problem I am facing is, how do I show the Orders and order history of a customer?

My orders table has orderId, productId, quantity and total price. but to show the product name, I have to use the productId and rerieve the Product name from product table.

I have no clue on how to do it.

Till now, i was  using the jstl foreach loop to iterate the products in the productList.jsp page and displaying them in a table. 
But as i told above, i need to retrieve data from 3-4 tables at once, like productName(from product table), productManuacturer(also from product table), ShippingAddress (from customer table). And I am unsure how to do this.

Edit 1: I asked this question from someone else's computer and didn't have my code with me then.
So, I am giving my code here.

1. Customer.java

   ```
   package com.site.model;

   import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
   import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty;
   import javax.persistence.*;
   import java.io.Serializable;

   @Entity
   public class Customer implements Serializable {

   private static final long serialVersionUID = -3280023076408333682L;

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue
   private int customerId;

   @NotEmpty(message = "  The customer name must not be blank.")
   private String customerName;

   @NotEmpty (message = "  The customer email must not be blank.")
   private String customerEmail;
   private String customerPhone;

   @NotEmpty (message = "  The username must not be blank.")
   private String username;

   @NotEmpty (message = "  The password must not be blank.")
   private String password;
   private boolean enabled;

   @OneToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "billingAddressId")
   private BillingAddress billingAddress;

   @OneToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "shippingAddressId")
   private ShippingAddress shippingAddress;

   @OneToOne()
   @JoinColumn(name = "cartId")
   @JsonIgnore
   private Cart cart;

   public int getCustomerId() {
       return customerId;
   }

   public void setCustomerId(int customerId) {
       this.customerId = customerId;
   }

   public String getCustomerName() {
       return customerName;
   }

   public void setCustomerName(String customerName) {
       this.customerName = customerName;
   }

   public BillingAddress getBillingAddress() {
       return billingAddress;
   }

   public void setBillingAddress(BillingAddress billingAddress) {
       this.billingAddress = billingAddress;
   }

   public ShippingAddress getShippingAddress() {
       return shippingAddress;
   }

   public void setShippingAddress(ShippingAddress shippingAddress) {
       this.shippingAddress = shippingAddress;
   }

   public String getCustomerPhone() {
       return customerPhone;
   }

   public void setCustomerPhone(String customerPhone) {
       this.customerPhone = customerPhone;
   }

   public String getCustomerEmail() {
       return customerEmail;
   }

   public void setCustomerEmail(String customerEmail) {
       this.customerEmail = customerEmail;
   }

   public String getUsername() {
       return username;
   }

   public void setUsername(String username) {
       this.username = username;
   }

   public String getPassword() {
       return password;
   }

   public void setPassword(String password) {
       this.password = password;
   }

   public boolean isEnabled() {
       return enabled;
   }

   public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
       this.enabled = enabled;
   }

   public Cart getCart() {
       return cart;
   }

   public void setCart(Cart cart) {
       this.cart = cart;
   }

   }
   ```
2. Cart.java

   package com.site.model;

   import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;

   import javax.persistence.*;
   import java.io.Serializable;
   import java.util.ArrayList;
   import java.util.List;

   @Entity
   public class Cart implements Serializable{

   private static final long serialVersionUID = -2479653100535233857L;

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue
   private int cartId;

   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "cart", cascade= CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
   private List cartItems = new ArrayList();

   @OneToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "customerId")
   @JsonIgnore
   private Customer customer;

   private double grandTotal;

   public int getCartId() {
       return cartId;
   }

   public void setCartId(int cartId) {
       this.cartId = cartId;
   }

   public double getGrandTotal() {
       return grandTotal;
   }

   public void setGrandTotal(double grandTotal) {
       this.grandTotal = grandTotal;
   }

   public List getCartItems() {
       return cartItems;
   }

   public void setCartItems(List cartItems) {
       this.cartItems = cartItems;
   }

   public Customer getCustomer() {
       return customer;
   }

   public void setCustomer(Customer customer) {
       this.customer = customer;
   }

   }
3. CartItem.java

   ```
   package com.site.model;
   ```

   import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;

   import javax.persistence.*;
   import java.io.Serializable;
   import java.util.List;

   @Entity
   public class CartItem implements Serializable{

   ```
   private static final long serialVersionUID = -904360230041854157L;

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue
   private int cartItemId;

   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name="cartId")
   @JsonIgnore
   private Cart cart;

   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "productId")
   private Product product;
   private int quantity;
   private double totalPrice;

   @ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="cartItems")
   @JsonIgnore
   private List<OrderHistory> orderHistoryList;

   public int getCartItemId() {
       return cartItemId;
   }

   public void setCartItemId(int cartItemId) {
       this.cartItemId = cartItemId;
   }

   public Product getProduct() {
       return product;
   }

   public void setProduct(Product product) {
       this.product = product;
   }

   public int getQuantity() {
       return quantity;
   }

   public void setQuantity(int quantity) {
       this.quantity = quantity;
   }

   public double getTotalPrice() {
       return totalPrice;
   }

   public void setTotalPrice(double totalPrice) {
       this.totalPrice = totalPrice;
   }

   public Cart getCart() {
       return cart;
   }

   public void setCart(Cart cart) {
       this.cart = cart;
   }

   public List<OrderHistory> getOrderHistoryList() {
       return orderHistoryList;
   }

   public void setOrderHistoryList(List<OrderHistory> orderHistoryList) {
       this.orderHistoryList = orderHistoryList;
   }
   }
   ```
4. CustomerOrder.java

   ```
   package com.site.model;
   ```

   import javax.persistence.*;
   import java.io.Serializable;

   @Entity
   public class CustomerOrder implements Serializable {

   ```
   private static final long serialVersionUID = -3608286390950243118L;

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue
   private int customerOrderId;

   @OneToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "cartId")
   private Cart cart;

   @OneToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "customerId")
   private Customer customer;

   @OneToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "billingAddressId")
   private BillingAddress billingAddress;

   @OneToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "shippingAddressId")
   private ShippingAddress shippingAddress;


   public int getCustomerOrderId() {
       return customerOrderId;
   }

   public void setCustomerOrderId(int customerOrderId) {
       this.customerOrderId = customerOrderId;
   }

   public Cart getCart() {
       return cart;
   }

   public void setCart(Cart cart) {
       this.cart = cart;
   }

   public Customer getCustomer() {
       return customer;
   }

   public void setCustomer(Customer customer) {
       this.customer = customer;
   }

   public BillingAddress getBillingAddress() {
       return billingAddress;
   }

   public void setBillingAddress(BillingAddress billingAddress) {
       this.billingAddress = billingAddress;
   }

   public ShippingAddress getShippingAddress() {
       return shippingAddress;
   }

   public void setShippingAddress(ShippingAddress shippingAddress) {
       this.shippingAddress = shippingAddress;
   }

   }
   ```
5. OrderHistory.java

   package com.site.model;

   import javax.persistence.*;
   import java.io.Serializable;
   import java.util.ArrayList;
   import java.util.List;

   @Entity
   public class OrderHistory implements Serializable {

   ```
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1083533250613139445L;

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue
   private int orderHistoryId;
   private int customerId;
   private String customerName;
   private int customerOrderId;
   private int cartId;

   @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
   @JoinTable(name = "cartItem_orderHistory", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "orderHistoryId"),
           inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn
                   (name = "cartItemId"))
   private List<CartItem> cartItems = new ArrayList<CartItem>();
   private double grandTotal;
   private String billingAddress;
   private String shippingAddress;

   public int getOrderHistoryId() {
       return orderHistoryId;
   }

   public void setOrderHistoryId(int orderHistoryId) {
       this.orderHistoryId = orderHistoryId;
   }

   public int getCustomerId() {
       return customerId;
   }

   public void setCustomerId(int customerId) {
       this.customerId = customerId;
   }

   public String getCustomerName() {
       return customerName;
   }

   public void setCustomerName(String customerName) {
       this.customerName = customerName;
   }

   public int getCustomerOrderId() {
       return customerOrderId;
   }

   public void setCustomerOrderId(int customerOrderId) {
       this.customerOrderId = customerOrderId;
   }

   public int getCartId() {
       return cartId;
   }

   public void setCartId(int cartId) {
       this.cartId = cartId;
   }

   public List<CartItem> getCartItems() {
       return cartItems;
   }

   public void setCartItems(List<CartItem> cartItems) {
       this.cartItems = cartItems;
   }

   public double getGrandTotal() {
       return grandTotal;
   }

   public void setGrandTotal(double grandTotal) {
       this.grandTotal = grandTotal;
   }

   public String getBillingAddress() {
       return billingAddress;
   }

   public void setBillingAddress(String billingAddress) {
       this.billingAddress = billingAddress;
   }

   public String getShippingAddress() {
       return shippingAddress;
   }

   public void setShippingAddress(String shippingAddress) {
       this.shippingAddress = shippingAddress;
   }
   }
   ```

edit 2: how do I store the data in the ustomerorder table and orderhistory table, and also, how do i show it on a jsp page?

Answer (score 3):

you should have a CustomerId column in order table for detecting the order is associated with which customer. Simply insert logged in userid in that and fetch the customer name by making join with customer table.

Answer (score 0):

You should have customerid in your order table. So that you can fetch the customer's order history by providing customerid.